# React-Redux Refactoring Container Logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got one container connected to one component. Its a select-suggestion component. The problem is that both my container and component are getting too much repeated logic and i want to solve this maybe creating a configuration file or receiving from props one config.

This is the code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { goToPageRequest as goToPageRequestCompetitions  } from '../ducks/competitions/index';
import { getSearchParam as getSearchCompetitionsParam, getCompetitionsList } from '../ducks/competitions/selectors';
import { goToPageRequest as goToPageRequestIntermediaries } from '../ducks/intermediaries/index';
import { getSearchParam as getSearchIntermediariesParam, getIntermediariesList } from '../ducks/intermediaries/selectors';
import SelectBox2 from '../components/SelectBox2';


export const COMPETITIONS_CONFIGURATION = {
    goToPageRequest: goToPageRequestCompetitions(),
    getSearchParam: getSearchCompetitionsParam(),
    suggestions: getCompetitionsList()
};

export const INTERMEDIARIES_CONFIGURATION = {
    goToPageRequest: goToPageRequestIntermediaries(),
    getSearchParam: getSearchIntermediariesParam(),
    suggestions: getIntermediariesList()
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    searchString: ownProps.reduxConfiguration.getSearchParam(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    dispatchGoToPage: goToPageRequestObj =>
        dispatch(ownProps.reduxConfiguration.goToPageRequest(goToPageRequestObj)),
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
    ...ownProps,
    search: searchParam => dispatchProps.dispatchGoToPage({
        searchParam
    }),
    ...stateProps
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(SelectBox2));






import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Flex, Box } from 'reflexbox';
import classname from 'classnames';
import styles from './index.scss';
import Input from '../Input';
import { AppButtonRoundSquareGray } from '../AppButton';
import RemovableList from '../RemovableList';

const MIN_VALUE_TO_SEARCH = 5;
const NO_SUGGESTIONS_RESULTS = 'No results found';


class SelectBox extends Component {
    /**
     * Component setup
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            displayBox: false,
            selection: null,
            value: '',
            items: [],
            suggestions: [],
        };
    }
    /**
     * Component lifecycle
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onClickOutside, false);
        if (this.props.suggestionsType){
            if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'competition'){
                this.state.suggestions = this.props.competitionsSuggestions;
            }
            if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'intermediaries'){
                this.state.suggestions = this.props.intermediariesSuggestions;
            }
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onClickOutside, false);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(this.props);
        if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'competition') {
             this.state.suggestions = nextProps.competitionsSuggestions;
         }
        if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'intermediaries') {
            this.state.suggestions = nextProps.intermediariesSuggestions;
        }
     }
    /**
     * DOM event handlers
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    onButtonClick = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const itemIncluded = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === this.state.selection);
        if (this.state.selection && !itemIncluded) {
            const item =
                this.state.suggestions.find(suggestion => suggestion.id === this.state.selection);
            this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, item] });
        }
    };
    onChangeList = (items) => {
        const adaptedItems = items
            .map(item => ({ label: item.name, id: item.itemName }));
        this.setState({ items: adaptedItems });
    };
    onClickOutside = (ev) => {
        if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(ev.target)) {
            this.setState({ displayBox: false });
        }
    };
    onSuggestionSelected = (ev) => {
        this.setState({
            displayBox: false,
            value: ev.target.textContent,
            selection: ev.target.id });
    };
    onInputChange = (ev) => {
        this.generateSuggestions(ev.target.value);
    };
    onInputFocus = () => {
        this.generateSuggestions(this.state.value);
    };
    /**
     * Helper functions
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    setWrapperRef = (node) => {
        this.wrapperRef = node;
    };
    executeSearch = (value) => {
        if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'competition'){
            this.props.searchCompetitions(value);
        }
        if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'intermediaries'){
            this.props.searchIntermediaries(value);
        }
    };
    generateSuggestions = (value) => {
        if (value.length > MIN_VALUE_TO_SEARCH) {
            this.executeSearch(value);
            this.setState({ displayBox: true, value, selection: '' });
        } else {
            this.setState({ displayBox: false, value, selection: '' });
        }
    };
    renderDataSuggestions = () => {
        const { listId } = this.props;
        const displayClass = this.state.displayBox ? 'suggestions-enabled' : 'suggestions-disabled';
        return (
            <ul
                id={listId}
                className={classname(styles['custom-box'], styles[displayClass], styles['select-search-box__select'])}
            >
                { this.state.suggestions.length !== 0 ?
                    this.state.suggestions.map(suggestion => (<li
                        className={classname(styles['select-search-box__suggestion'])}
                        onClick={this.onSuggestionSelected}
                        id={suggestion.get(this.props.suggestionsOptions.id)}
                        key={suggestion.get(this.props.suggestionsOptions.id)}
                    >
                        <span>{suggestion.get(this.props.suggestionsOptions.label)}</span>
                    </li>))
                    :
                    <li className={(styles['select-search-box__no-result'])}>
                        <span>{NO_SUGGESTIONS_RESULTS}</span>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        );
    };

    renderRemovableList = () => {
        if (this.state.items.length > 0) {
            const adaptedList = this.state.items
                .map(item => ({ name: item.name, itemName: item.id }));
            return (<RemovableList
                value={adaptedList}
                className={classname(styles['list-box'])}
                onChange={this.onChangeList}
                uniqueIdentifier="itemName"
            />);
        }
        return '';
    };

    render() {
        const input = {
            onChange: this.onInputChange,
            onFocus: this.onInputFocus,
            value: this.state.value
        };
        return (
            <Flex className={styles['form-selectBox']}>
                <Box w={1}>
                    <div
                        ref={this.setWrapperRef}
                        className={styles['div-container']}
                    >
                        <Input
                            {...this.props}
                            input={input}
                            list={this.props.listId}
                            inputStyle={classname('form-input--bordered', 'form-input--rounded', styles.placeholder)}
                        />
                        { this.renderDataSuggestions() }
                    </div>
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <AppButtonRoundSquareGray type="submit" className={styles['add-button']} onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
                        Add
                    </AppButtonRoundSquareGray>
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    { this.renderRemovableList() }
                </Box>
            </Flex>
        );
    }
}


SelectBox.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    listId: PropTypes.string,
    className: PropTypes.string
};

SelectBox.defaultProps = {
    items: [],
    placeholder: 'Choose an option...',
    listId: null,
    className: ''
};

export default SelectBox;
```

As you see, in many places i am validating the type of suggestions and do something with that. Its suppose to be a reusable component, and this component could accept any kind of type of suggestions. If this grows, if will have very big validations and i don't want that. So i think that i want something similar to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    searchString: ownProps.reduxConfiguration.getSearchParam(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    dispatchGoToPage: goToPageRequestObj =>
        dispatch(ownProps.reduxConfiguration.goToPageRequest(goToPageRequestObj)),
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
    ...ownProps,
    search: searchParam => dispatchProps.dispatchGoToPage({
        searchParam
    }),
    ...stateProps
});
```

How can i make something similar to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to consider:

*The purpose of using Redux is to remove state logic from your components.*

What you've currently got has Redux providing some state *and* your component providing some state. **This is an anti-pattern (bad)**:

```
// State from Redux: (line 22 - 24)
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  searchString: ownProps.reduxConfiguration.getSearchParam(state),
});


// State from your component: (line 65 - 71)
this.state = {
  displayBox: false,
  selection: null,
  value: '',
  items: [],
  suggestions: [],
};
```

If you take another look at your SelectBox component - a lot of what it is doing is *selecting state*:

```
// The component is parsing the state and choosing what to render (line 79 - 86)
if (this.props.suggestionsType){
  if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'competition'){
    this.state.suggestions = this.props.competitionsSuggestions;
  }
  if (this.props.suggestionsType === 'intermediaries'){
    this.state.suggestions = this.props.intermediariesSuggestions;
  }
}
```

Turns out, *this is precisely what `mapStateToProps()` is for*.  You should move this selection logic to `mapStateToProps()`. Something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  let suggestions = null;
  switch (state.suggestionType) {
    case 'competition':
      suggestions = state.suggestions.competition;
      break;
    case 'intermediaries':
      suggestions = state.suggestions.intermediaries;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return {
    suggestions
  };
};
```

Every time the state updates (in Redux) it will pass new props to your component. Your component should only be concerned with how to render its part of the state. And this leads me to my next point: When your application state is all being managed by Redux and you don't have state logic in your components, *your components can simply be functions* (functional components).

```
const SelectBox3 = ({ suggestions }) => {
  const onClick = evt => { console.log('CLICK!'); };
  const list = suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index} onClick={onClick}>suggestion</li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {list}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Applying these patterns, you get components that are *very easy to reason about*, and that is a big deal if you want to maintain this code into the future.

Also, by the way, you don't need to use `mergeProps()` in your example. mapDispatchToProps can just return your search function since `connect()` will automatically assemble the final props object for you.:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  // 'search' will be a key on the props object passed to the component!
  search: searchParam => {
    dispatch(ownProps.reduxConfiguration.goToPageRequest({ searchParam });
    // (also, your 'reduxConfiguration' is probably something that belongs in
    // the Redux state.) 
  }
});
```

I highly recommend giving the Redux docs a good read-through. Dan Abramov (and crew) have done a great job of laying it all out in there and explaining why the patterns are the way they are.

Here's the link: [**Redux**](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html).

Also, look into [async actions and redux-thunk](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators) for dealing with asynchronous calls (for performing a search on a server, for example).

Finally let me say: you're on the right track. Keep working on it, and soon you will know the joy of writing elegant functional components for your web apps.  Good luck!